# Should I join a join table to another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design

Let's say I am building a potluck organizing app. I have a join table tracking Participants and Events (MTM), I also have a Dishes table with dishes that are unique and associated to each Participant (OTM). Participants will sign up to events and agree to bring one or more of their Dishes.

The ParticipantEvents join table will track the RSVP but what is the best way to track which dishes the Participant is contributing to that Event?

Should I create a join table between the Dishes and the Events?
Should I create a join table between the ParticipantEvents join table and the Dishes table (ParticipantEventsDishes)?
Is there a better way?

Comment: I would create a join table between dishes and participant_events.

Comment: What @Pablo said. Also, I would consider making is so that a participant can sign up to bring many dishes to an event - in case your participants are feeling generous.

Comment: How's the association between Participants  and dishes? just using Dishes.participant_id ? How about showing all your tables and fields in your question?

Comment: brookz, You've got it right. "...a Dishes table with dishes that are unique and associated to each Participant (OTM)." One Participant has many Dishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case looks like a three way (ternary) relationship  to me.  So I would create a three way join table, with three foreign keys.

```
Promised (DishID, EventID, ParticipantID)
```

Now you can join this with all three tables to produce the details for all participants.  Note that a participant can promise more than one dish for an event.

Comment: I see. So with this design, a Participant attending an Event, bringing 2 Dishes, would use 2 rows of data. This sounds like the best solution so far!